# How do I resolve one hot encoding if my test data has missing values in a col?

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

For example if my training data has the categorical values (1,2,3,4,5) in the col,then one hot encoding will give me 5 cols. But in the test data I have, say only 4 out of the 5 values i.e.(1,3,4,5).So one hot encoding will give me only 4 cols.Therefore if I apply my trained weights on the test data, I will get an error as the dimensions of the cols do not match in the train and test data, dim(4)!=dim(5).Any suggestions on what do I do with the missing col values?
The image of my code is provided below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYqA3.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first combine two dataframes, then get_dummies then split them so they can have exact number of columns i.e

```
#Example Dataframes 
Xtrain = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.array([4,2,3,5,3,1])})
Xtest = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.array([4,5,1,3])})


# Concat with keys then get dummies
temp = pd.get_dummies(pd.concat([Xtrain,Xtest],keys=[0,1]), columns=['x'])

# Selecting data from multi index and assigning them i.e
Xtrain,Xtest = temp.xs(0),temp.xs(1)

# Xtrain.as_matrix()
# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

# Xtest.as_matrix()

# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Do not follow this approach. Its a simple trick with lot of disadvantages. @Vast Academician answer explains better.

Comment: Is there a way by which we can specify the no. of cols like for (1,2,3) I want to have 5 cols instead of 3 , so that if in the training data its like (1,2,3,4,5) it will work without any problems on the test data with(1,2,3) as well

Comment: Can u suggest how to use it with sparse=True argument in get_dummies()?

Answer (score 17):

Guys don't do this mistake, please!

Yes, you can do this hack with the concatenation of train and test and fool yourself, but the real problem is in production. There your model will someday face an unknown level of your categorical variable and then break.

In reality, some of the more viable options could be:

1. Retrain your model periodically to account for new data.
2. Do not use one hot. Seriously, there are many better options like leave one out encoding (https://www.kaggle.com/c/caterpillar-tube-pricing/discussion/15748#143154) conditional probability encoding (https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/designing-machine-learning-models-7d0048249e69), target encoding to name a few. Some classifiers like CatBoost even have a built-in mechanism for encoding, there are mature libraries like target_encoders in Python, where you will find lots of other options.
3. Embed categorical features and this could save you from a complete retrain (http://flovv.github.io/Embeddings_with_keras/)

Comment: Coundn't agree less when it comes to production level.

Answer (score 0):

Use dummy(binary) encoding instead of one hot encoding. Pandas `pd.dummies()` with `drop_first = True` creates dummy encoding to get k-1 dummies out of k categorical levels by removing the first level. The default option `drop_first = False` creates one hot encoding.

[See pandas official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Also dummy(binary) encoding creates less number of columns.